# Get average value from multiple input fields(range)

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic

I have been searching for a solution for days, i am an beginner in javascript.

This is the form i use to input value via sliders.

```
                    <div class="formSliderField" style="display:block">
                        <div class="formIcons" id="formSliderImage1"></div>
                        <div class="formSlider"  id="formSlider1">
                            <input class="slider" name="cat_pk" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="0.5" width="290px" value="0" onchange="field1(this.value)"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="formMark"><p id="formMark1" class="mark">1</p></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="formSliderField" style="display:block">
                        <div class="formIcons" id="formSliderImage2"></div>
                        <div class="formSlider" id="formSlider2">
                            <input class="slider" name="cat_service" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="0.5" width="290px" value="0" onchange="field2(this.value)"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="formMark"><p id="formMark2" class="mark">1</p></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="formSliderField" style="display:block">
                        <div class="formIcons" id="formSliderImage3"></div>
                        <div class="formSlider" id="formSlider3">
                            <input class="slider" name="cat_prijs" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="0.5" width="290px" value="0" onchange="field3(this.value)"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="formMark"><p id="formMark3" class="mark">1</p></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="formSubmitWrapper">
                        <div id="formSubmitButton">
                        <input id="formRecensieSubmit" type="submit" value="Bevestigen"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I need the input value from these sliders to get an average for further use. This needs to be as dynamic as possible, not after i submit this form.

You can see i use onchange, this is already used in a function to display the input values per slider.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***JavaScript :***

```
window.onload = function(){
   var elements=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]')
   for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){ 
      elements[i].addEventListener('change',calcul , false);
   }
}

function calcul(){
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="range"]')
  var len = 0
  var buf = 0
  for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
    if(elements[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.display != 'none'){
      buf += parseInt(elements[i].value)
      len++
    }
  }
  buf = len === 0 ? 0 : buf/len
  console.log(buf)
}
```

#### [CodeOpen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DxuIK)

Comment: in my console log it only gives NaN. and doesnt change any value. dont know why...

Comment: @user2971991 : Update my jsfiddle with your js code and post here

Comment: you do not have a jsfiddle yet, so i cant modify it

Comment: @user2971991 : then create one

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DCkyr, jsfiddle is down so... I want to get an average from only the visible sliders atm(sliders can be turned on/of in the future)

Comment: @user2971991 : Updated with example.If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to achieve something like this?

```
(function (win, doc, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    var myForm = doc.getElementById("myForm"),
        sliders = myForm.getElementsByClassName("slider"),
        marks = myForm.getElementsByClassName("mark");

    myForm.addEventListener("change", changeHandler);

    function changeHandler(e) {
        var t = e.target,
            i = -1,
            sum = 0,
            avg = 0;

        if (t.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "input" && t.type.toLowerCase() === "range") {
            i = [].indexOf.call(sliders, t);
            marks[i].innerHTML = t.value;

            [].forEach.call(sliders, function (val) {
                sum += parseFloat(val.value);
            });

            avg = parseFloat((sum / sliders.length).toFixed(1));
        }
        console.log(avg);
    }
}(window, window.document));
```

Look at [***Demonstration***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/kCA4W/)

Comment: In my current form i already have the ability to show the value of each slider next to each slider. I want to combine these values into one value and divide it by the number of sliders i use. I need that end value for further use. hope i made it clearer now.